# JQuery writes to one input field but not one in a different table

Tags: javascript, jquery

A bit of background. I'm a hobbyist coder trying to keep my brain active in retirement. I've written an art website with content manager for my wife using PHP/MySQL. I've now set myself a project to learn a lot more about Javascript and JQuery.

The project I've set for this winter is a sailing navigation aid. When you go across the tides it is necessary to allow for the tidal stream pushing you off course. The amount of tidal offset is given in tidal stream atlases and they run from HW - 6 hours to HW + 6 hours in 1 hour step. When going on a long trip such as crossing the channel the trip can cross 2 high waters times and there is a bit of fiddling at the overlap between +6 HW1 9+ 6 hours and HW2 - 6 hours.

I have three tables The first collects the basic data, HW1, HW2, distance, speed, depart time etc. This is used to calculate the times of each hour for looking up and in the tidal atlas. The second table is all the various tidal stream hours, distance travelled in each hour and the associated rate and bearing of tidal stream. I also use it to store the x and y after I have resolved the bearing.

Table 3 stores results and doesn't affect this question.

I have written a validation function that checks the distance inputs and if invalid turns the background red and writes '' in to the input value.

```
function validateDistance(inputField) {
var speed = document.getElementById("speed").value; 
var passageDistance = document.getElementById("passageDistance").value;
var sumDistance = sumTidalStreamDistnces();

var isValid = !isNaN(inputField.value);

if (isValid && (inputField.value > speed)) {
    alert("You are planning on travelling " + inputField.value +" miles in this hour which is greater than the planned speed (" +speed +"kn). \nThe entry will be used in calculations but the field wil be flagged red as a reminder");
    isValid = false;
}

if (isValid) {
    inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#bfa';
} else {
    inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#fba';
    $("#" + inputField.id).val('').value;

}

// check that the passage distance is completed otherwise change distance calculate red

if (sumDistance === passageDistance) {
    $("#totDistance").val('').css('background-color','#bfa');
} else {
    $("#totDistance").val('').css('background-color','#fba');
}

 $("#totDistance").val(sumDistance).value;
 return isValid;
```

This works well on the first table for the passage distance:

```
    <tr>
        <td>Distance</td>
        <td><input name="passageDistance" id="passageDistance" placeholder="distance" onChange="validateDistance(this); calcPassageTime(); calcETA()" > </td>
    </tr>
```

However in the tidal stream table it turns the background red but doesn't reset the value:

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="hw1+0" id="hw1+0" placeholder="HW" disabled = "disabled" size = "6" > </td>
    <td><input name="hw1+0Time" id="hw1+0Time" class="time"  placeholder="hh:mm" class="resetHW1" disabled = "disabled" size = "6" > </td>
    <td><input name="hw1+0From" id="hw1+0From" class="from" placeholder="hh:mm" class="resetHW1" disabled = "disabled" size = "6" > </td>
    <td><input name="hw1+0To" id="hw1+0To" class="to" placeholder="hh:mm" class="resetHW1" disabled = "disabled" size = "6" > </td>
    **<td><input name="hw1+0Distance" id="hw1+0Distance" onchange="validateDistance(this); calcTides(this)" placeholder="miles" class="distance"   size = "6" > </td>**
    <td><input name="hw1+0Rate" id="hw1+0Rate" onchange="validateRate(this);calcTides(this)" placeholder="rate (kn)" class="rate" size = "6"  > </td>
    <td><input name="hw1+0Direction" id="hw1+0Direction" onchange="validateBearing(this);calcTides(this)"  placeholder="degrees" class="direction" size = "6" > </td>
    <td><input name="hw1+0North" id="hw1+0North" class="north"  placeholder="" disabled = "disabled" size = "6" > </td>
    <td><input name="hw1+0West" id="hw1+0West" class="west"  placeholder="" disabled = "disabled" size = "6" > </td>
</tr>
```

(there's another 25 table blocks like this, the only difference is the prefix to the id eg hw1+1distance)

In the first case for passage distance if I enter, say, "k" then the field is cleared by the validation code and the placeholder shows. However in the tidal stream cases if I enter "k" it displays a "k" but does change the background red.

I have highlighted the relevant line of code. I've tried changing the id to something neutral like "temp" and removing all extraneous information. I've used used firefox debugger to check that the code is being read and it shows the relevant line being executed.

Apologies for being a bit long winded, I hope it makes sense?

Comment: `$("#" + inputField.id).val('').value;` should be just `inputField.value = '';`

Comment: Just tried that and now it doesn't clear either field.

Answer (score 0):

The line $("#" + inputField.id).val('').value; looks a bit strange to me. Clear the value, sure. But what's the .value supposed to be in this case? That's a return, but you're not capturing it(?).

However, that it works on one of them and not the other is also interesting. I would put some console.log(...) statements in and verify that the selector is actually correct in both cases, according to your assumptions.

BTW: for a "hobbyist" coder, your code is pretty good in general. :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I try to do things "correctly" by reading around the web but often take shortcuts.

Comment: We all take short-cuts, especially when the time pressure's on. :D The trick is to balance it all in reasonable way, and that takes experience and constant mindfulness. Good luck to you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

For some reason JQuery doesn't like the "+" symbol in the id. I thought I'd read that they were acceptable but obviously not.